# I am using subprocess RUN to exceute multiple shell scripts as per my need.Why its is getting Deadlock/stuck

Tags: python, subprocess

This is my function which executes the scripts.

```
def script_execute(args,row):
    """
    Executes the script using suprocess.run by using the given arguments in variable args.
    """
    retry=2
    att=0
    timeout=600
    print(args)
    while att < retry:
            args = [str(x) if x!=None else '' for x in args]
            try:
                
                result = run(args,stdout=DEVNULL,stderr=DEVNULL,timeout=timeout)
                print(result.returncode)


                if result.returncode:
                 
                  current_time = str(datetime.now())
                  error_string ="script execution failed for arguments: " + str(result.args) +"\n"+ result.stderr
                  error_list = [(current_time,row['sourcepath'],row['bigdataid'],"failed",error_string,current_time,"PushDistributor")]
                  insert_log(error_list)
                  return False
                else:
                  
                  return True

            except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
               
                continue
            else:
               
                break
            finally:
               
                att +=1
                timeout +=300
```

So what I have done is introduced timeout which is set 600 secs or 10 mins initially. If the subprocess takes longer time than that it raises Timeout exception and in finally block 300 sec is added to initial timeout for 1 more retry.
I dont want to use timeout so is there any other sleek way of doing it without the use of timeout and why subprocess gets stuck or deadlock even if have set stdout and stderr as DEVNULL.
Need HELP with this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What is the script - problem could lie there ? 
Please try to format your code example properly

Comment: basically each scripts has its own function such as unzipping a files or regex matching on files or simply copy files from one location to another etc.  I don't think there is a issue with scripts.